# If I open smtp server through a web browser

Tags: http, browser, smtp

I am studying about smtp, http and various application layer protocols. I was wondering what will happen when I type smtp.gmail.com (or any other mail server) in my web browser.

For me, it says it waits for a long time and then show Internal Server Error. It does not show error like No Page Found. Why is that?

As far as I understand, smtp.gmail.com won't return an html page, so web browser should throw an error. Also how does my browser know which port to connect? SMTP servers use different port than HTTP servers, I guess. So ...

What exactly is happening when I connect to smtp.gmail.com?

**EDIT:**

It gives `502` status code which means `The server was acting as a gateway or proxy and received an invalid response from the upstream server`. I don't understand this. 
The web browser should not connect to `smtp.gmail.com` in the first place as it listens on a different port than 80. So it should give `404 Not Found` error. So what exactly is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Your browser knows that HTTP is on port 80 by default. Check [default ports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers)
smtp.gmail.com has port 25 open and not 80. That is why browser cannot connect and also because it does not "understand" SMTP. You can connect an email client like Thunderbird or MS Outlook.